# Interesting Examples of Convex Non Smooth Functions with Non Trivial Proximal Operators

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, proximal-operators

I'm experimenting with optimizing convex functional with proximal operator methods. The main problem is I cannot come up with interesting non-smooth functions. I use various combinations of indicator functions and $ {L}_{1} $ norms, but those are boring. Could you please suggest any interesting ideas?

Comment: How about some problems from image processing like debluring an image or doing an MRI reconstruction? Or maybe a machine learning problem like training a support vector machine.

Comment: @littleO those are great ideas, could you give me some digestible references?

Comment: How about $\ell_p$ norms with $p \in [1, 2)$.

Comment: Hey, it's not our fault if you think the absolute value is boring. I for one think it's beautifully simple. :-)

Comment: What about solving the unanswered question in Math Exchange? See https://math.stackexchange.com/search?page=3&tab=Relevance&q=Proximal%20Operator.

Answer (score 3):

An interesting set of examples of nonsmooth convex functions are the [Lovasz extensions of submodular set functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.6453). In general they are nonsmooth at points where components are equal (e.g. $x$ such that $x_i = x_j$ for some $i \ne j$).

If you want a very interesting function, one that's NP-hard just to evaluate, consider the optimal value of max-cut as a function of the weights:

$$
f(w) = \max_{x \in \{-1,1\}^n} \sum_{i,j} x_i w_{ij} x_j
$$

This is the maximum of linear functions of $w$, so it's clearly a convex function of $w$, but evaluating it in general requires solving a maximum cut problem. (Even though it's an NP-hard problem, you can still solve by brute force when the number of dimensions is small if you just want a toy example.) It's the convex conjugate of the indicator function of the cut polyhedron.

Comment: Great examples, exactly kind of staff I've been looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I might not fully understand your question, but $x \mapsto |x|$ is convex and not smooth at $0$, so doesn't it satisfy your needs?

More generally, if $V$ is a normed space and $\{p_1, \dots, p_n\} \subset V$, then $x \mapsto \| x - p_1 \| + \dots + \| x - p_n \|$ will be convex (as the sum of convex functions) with singular points precisely at $p_1, \dots, p_n$.

Comment: Yes, but it is a boring function, with only one not smooth point.

Comment: @Moonwalker: True that, I have added some spices to the mix.

Answer (score 1):

For any nonempty convex subset $S$ of a normed linear space, the distance to $S$ is a convex function.

The Legendre transform of a convex function is a convex function.

In equilibrium statistical mechanics of lattice systems, the pressure in a convex function of the interaction.  First-order phase transitions occur where it is non-differentiable.

Comment: That's great, could you give me some digestible references? About those statistical mechanics lattice systems and such.

Comment: You might try Simon, [The Statistical Mechanics of Lattice Gases, vol 1](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/5262.html).  I guess I can be forgiven for also mentioning my own [Convexity in the Theory of Lattice Gases](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/603.html).